# vbs silent and graceful taskkill all chrome process

Tags: google-chrome, vbscript

Is there any way for this code:

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "taskkill /im chrome.exe", 0, True
```

Instead of only closing only one window of chrome silently and gracefully like this script already does, I want it to close all running instances of chrome.

If there is a simple way to close all windows of chrome without a loop with this code, that would be perfect.

I have already tried all other methods, but they all either didn't close gracefully, (terminate), or they showed some sort of command prompt or loading bar.

If there isn't any way to do this without a loop, then so be it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can perform this using WMI service . We can count all the running instances of chrome and then silently kill it one by one.

Hope this helps . It involves looping .

```
Dim oShell, objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess, strComputer, processName,instances

strComputer = "."
instances = 0
processName = "chrome.exe"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")

For Each objProcess in colProcess
If objProcess.Name = processName Then instances = instances + 1        'Incrementing Running Instances
Next

Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

Do While instances > 0
oShell.Run "taskkill /im chrome.exe", 0, True       'Killing one instance at a time
instances = instances - 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for instance count  `For Each`  doing this roles. It's go through all processes in task list and check the name of process you provide in your query and then its deal with this process in the way you like. If you want kill this process use  `Terminate` method this more easy to kill multi instance of one process name.

```
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess, strComputer

strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process where name= 'chrome.exe'")

For Each objProcess in colProcess

objProcess.terminate()

Next
WScript.quit
```

**OR** short way away of query style :

```
Dim Processes,Process
Set Processes = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_Process")

For Each Process In Processes

    If StrComp(Process.Name, "chrome.exe", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
       Process.Terminate()
    End If

Next

WScript.Quit
```

**OR**

```
Dim Processes,Process
Set Processes = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_Process")

For Each Process In Processes

    If Instr( 1, process.Name, "chrome", vbTextCompare ) > 0 Then
       Process.Terminate()
    End If

Next

WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code, it is similar to Alt+F4

```
oShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"
```

You have to make sure that chrome is the active window.